# launching video at application launch fails iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to show a small video (3 sec video) every time when user opens the application on iOS device.
(If the app is opened from memory then don't show video)

I am having my "dashboard" view as root view controller.

I searched all the links on SO and other sites, but none helps.

Sometimes my video is working but later application get crashed.

My dashboardview is from "Main.storyboard" but there are no controls on storyboard.
Only linking of navigation bar is done via storyboard.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self showVideo];
}


- (void)showVideo
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSLog(@"video path :- %@",url);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.videoController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    //[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.videoController animated:NO];

    [self.videoController.moviePlayer play];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.videoController];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)_notification
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [self.videoController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.videoController.moviePlayer stop];
    self.videoController = nil;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

the nslog is printing video path correctly.
like

```
video path :- file:///Users/itshastra/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/87C93694-66E8-4884-B087-10E1E4CBA4D1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DB6C89D4-EE6D-4830-B208-B4AA89FD8E59/Complaint.app/video.mp4
```

But App get crashed,
Neither it shows the video and then dashboard, not dashboard directly.

Can any one please guide me, what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

If by mistake I missed any link on SO, please provide that as well.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it to call [self showVideo]; from viewWillAppear method?

Comment: Yes, I tried. but it shows black screen nothing else. App get freezes there.

Comment: Have you added your video into Xcode directory or Copy bundle resources?

Comment: yes, its added there.
I have checked that too...

Comment: @stallone is it a splash screen video? asking because showing splash screen video in MPMoviePlayerController is not that much user friendly. You can show splash screen video using AVPlayer.

Comment: @Bhushan, yes
its splash screen video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling method like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    [self performSelector:@selector(showVideo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f]; 
}
```

Comment: didn't work.
Worked only once. then App crashed,
also didn't received the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

Comment: @RajeshMaurya Rather then this you need to put condition in to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` which is a best solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the option "Enable Zombie Objects" under following path:
Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Enable Zombie Objects

and let me know the logs.